# Twisted Proxy with range splitting

Tags: python, http, proxy, twisted

I want to write a twisted proxy that splits up very large GET request into smaller fixed size ranges and sends it on to another proxy (using the Range: bytes). The other proxy doesn't allow large responses and when the response is to large it returns a 502.

How can I implement a proxy in twisted that on a 502 error it tries splitting the request into smaller allowed chunks. The documentation is hard to follow. I know I need to extend ProxyRequest, but from there I'm a bit stuck.

It doesn't have to be a twisted proxy, but it seems to be easily modified and I managed to at least get it to forward the request unmodified to the proxy by just setting the connectTCP to my proxy (in ProxyRequest.parsed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending ProxyRequest is probably not the easiest way to do this, actually; ProxyRequest pretty strongly assumes that one request = one response, whereas here you want to split up a single request into multiple requests.

Easier would be to simply write a [Resource](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.web.resource.Resource.html) implementation that does what you want, which briefly would be:

1. in `render_GET`, construct a URL to make several outgoing requests using [`Agent`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.web.client.Agent.html)
2. return `NOT_DONE_YET`
3. as each response comes in, call `request.write` on your original incoming requests, and then issue a new request with a `Range` header
4. finally when the last response comes in, call `request.finish` on your original request

You can simply construct a [`Site`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.5.0/api/twisted.web.server.Site.html) object with your `Resource`, and set `isLeaf` on your `Resource` to true so your `Resource` doesn't have to implement any traversal logic and can just build the URL using `request.prePathURL` and `request.postpath`.  (`request.postpath` is sadly undocumented; it's a list of the not-yet-traversed path segments in the request).

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of trying to overide a Site. Was trying to make the proxy work for my problem.